# BASH/LINUX - Problem with iterative sum in a loop (decimal numbers )

Tags: linux, bash, sum, iteration, syntax-error

I have a .csv file where I select the first column (variable "a") and later I change the dot (.) by comma (,), it is the variable "acomma".

I am trying to sum all the values of this column with a loop (see code) but I always have the same mistake (see pic):

**"syntax error: operand expected"**

Curiusly the sum do it well (5129).

[Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Y1Qg.png):

```
while IFS=; read -r line;
do
a=$(echo $line | awk -F "\"*;\"*" '{print $1}')
acomma=$(echo $a | sed 's/\./,/')
let fixed_acidity=$(bc <<< "scale=1; $fixed_acidity + $acomma")


done < winequality-white_sincabecera.csv

echo $fixed_acidity
```

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FJC1n.png):

[image: Output]

Can anyone help me with this? The aim is the sum of decimal in a iterative process.

Comment: because `bc` doesn't understand the comma : compare `bc <<< "scale=1;1+1,0"` and `bc <<< "scale=1;1+1.0"`

Comment: You are right, but when I do the sum with dot (.), the result is not correct. It is 46877.85 when it has to be 5129. ¿Do you know what is the problem?
Thanks!